# How to use a javascript function from a React js component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I have index.js, that is a javascript file with no classes which uses RenderDOM to render the component timeline and initialize some arrays with data, and index.js have a function playSound(), I have sent playSound as a prop to timeline, but it returns error  this.props.playSound is not a function.

For a different function name i.e. "playSound()" it works, but with"onPlayFrames" it don't get recognized as function on timeline.jsx

I send the prop like this: (index.js)

```
function onPlayFrames(arg){
    // Code to play a sound with arg
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Timeline onPlayFrames={onPlayFrames}/>
    ,document.getElementById("root")
)
```

and use it on timeline like this: (timeline.jsx)

```
class Timeline extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
          super(props);
      }

  playStop(arg) {
      this.props.onPlayFrames(arg);
  }
}
```

i just get the error  "this.state.onPlayFrames is not a function" when i try to use the function, it doesn't matters what i do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within timeline.jsx:

```
playStop(arg) {
  this.props.onPlayFrames(arg);
}
```

This should `this.props.playSound(arg)`.  The reason is because it has to match what you are using as a property na:

```
<Timeline playSound={playSound}/>
```

---

To make it clearer, imagine you did this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Timeline foobar={onPlayFrames}/>
    ,document.getElementById("root")
)
```

The Property on Timeline is now `foobar` which means on Timeline, it will be passed the onPlayFrames function via a property called `foobar`.

```
class Timeline extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
          super(props);
      }

  playStop(arg) {
      this.props.foobar(arg);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have written the code wrong, but, when I try using the name "onPlayFrames", it just doesn't works, with "playSound", it works perfectly, any idea of why?

Comment: I have updated the answer to help explain why it works and what the relationship is because what prop names

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this code pen.Is this what your asking?

```
function playSound(){
  alert("faf");// Code to play a sound with arg
}
class Test extends React.Component{
render(){
  return <button onClick={()=>this.props.play()}>faf</button>
}
}
const Parent = ()=> <Test play={playSound}/>;

ReactDOM.render(
  <h1><Parent/></h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```